# What is an $NP^{NP}$-complete problem?

Tags: complexity-classes, np, answer-set-programming

So in this paper I'm reading (https://adamsmith.as/papers/fdg2013_shortcuts.pdf), the authors talk about an $NP^{NP}$-complete problem, in relation to Answer Set Programming. I know what P, NP, etc. are but I don't unerstand what they mean with $NP^{NP}$. Also I can't Google it because Google doesn't recognize superscript.

I did find out it's also mentioned in [this book](https://books.google.nl/books?id=LfteAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=%22npnp%22+complete&source=bl&ots=PSip06Se_r&sig=vGxXxS4Lp92qJwWvLHC_r8X8GyY&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=fMURVamhEsfSU5W7gqAM&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22npnp%22&f=false), but they still don't provide an explanation.

Can anyone ecplain this class of problems to me?

Comment: $NP^{NP}$ is the set of languages in which you can query any language in $NP$ in constant time (by invoking an "oracle"), that are also checkable in polynomial time (definition of $NP$). Similarly, $P^{NP}$ is the set of languages solvable in polynomial time while also having access to an oracle that can decide membership in any language in $NP$ in constant time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$NP$ is the class of problems that, roughly speaking, you can solve by guessing an $y$ of polynomial size (with some magic to guarantee that you guess "right") and then doing a polynomial computation involving $y$ and the original input.

$NP^{NP}$ is the class of problems solvable in this way, if you have access to an oracle for $NP$. After guessing $y$, you're not just allowed to do some polynomial computation, you're also allowed (within this calculation) to solve problems from $NP$ (through an oracle, so in constant time).

The classical $NP$-complete problem of boolean satisfiability is to compute $\exists_x R(x)$ where $R$ is some boolean formula (and $x$ is a shorthand for $x_1,\ldots,x_n$). Its $NP^{NP}$-complete analogue is to compute $\exists_x \forall_y R(x)$.

A slightly more intuitive $NP^{NP}$-complete problem is that of formula minimization: given a formula, can you find a formula of length $\leq k$ that expresses the same (boolean) function?

$NP^{NP}$ is also known as $\Sigma_2 P$, and you will be able to find more info by searching for "polynomial hierarchy" (see, e.g., [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy)).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So would it be acceptable to say that $NP^{NP}$-complete problems can be verified in polynomial time, if you had a black box that could solve $NP$-complete problems? Or did I misunderstand?